# Passing exception in masstransit request-response model

Tags: c#, exception, masstransit

I have UI client which communicate with server application via masstransit over rabbitmq. So, I want to catch exceptions of UserException type on client and show it's content to user, all works fine but problem is each message from client to server, that produce exception on server, moves to error queue. But im my logic this is not system error, it's just user warning, not more. How to avoid moving such messages to error queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [consume faults via `Fault<>`](http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/usage/exceptions.html#consuming-faults). It looks like that part works for you.

What you want is a replacement [`MoveExceptionToTransportFilter`](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit/Pipeline/Filters/MoveExceptionToTransportFilter.cs) that would filter out those messages getting tossed in the error queue.

Comment: I think this is what i need, but i use masstransit 2.9.0.0. Is there any possibility to add such filter?

Comment: There are no plans to add this to 2.x release, but open an issue on GitHub, https://GitHub.com/MassTransit/masstransit, to make sure we know of your interest.